# Convert a list of tuples of strings to a list of strings

Tags: clojure

If I have a query:

```
(def results_01 
       (projectResults "JHotDraw54b1" 
             (fn [] (damp.ekeko/ekeko [?tdn (l/fresh [ ?invoker ?invokedmethod]
                          (cts/calls ?invoker ?tdn "toolDone" ?invokedmethod))))))
```

that gives me a list of tuples of strings as result, I need to convert this list to a list of strings how I can do that in Clojure.

The results are :

```
   #{("ActionTool") ("CompositeFigureCreationTool") ("DrawApplet") ("CreationTool") ("NestedCreationTool") ("URLTool") ("ConnectionTool") ("MDI_DrawApplication") ("DrawApplication")}
```

Comment: Is the query a necessary part of the question? What you have is a set of lists of Strings, where each list has only one element in it.

Comment: Yes the important prat is the set and how I can convert is to a list of strings

Answer (score 3):

That's a set not a list - `#{}` denotes a set, enclosing all its elements. `()` does the same for a list.

```
(def stuff #{'("ActionTool") '("CompositeFigureCreationTool") '("DrawApplet") '("CreationTool") '("NestedCreationTool") '("URLTool") 
         '("ConnectionTool") '("MDI_DrawApplication") '("DrawApplication")})

(defn change-stuff []
  (apply concat stuff))
```

`(change-stuff)` will give you a list of Strings:

```
("ActionTool" "CompositeFigureCreationTool" "DrawApplet" "CreationTool" "NestedCreationTool" "URLTool" "ConnectionTool" "MDI_DrawApplication" "DrawApplication")
```

If you want a set back then:

```
(into #{} (change-stuff))
```

Comment: and what if I want it as a set { }

Comment: That's a map not a set! You would use `into`.

Comment: np. Remember you can always edit your question to make it simpler to read for people that come along later. Also you can edit the title. You really need to get rid of the word 'tuple'.